# 500 Internal Server Error After DNS Changes

Tags: php, dns, internal-server-error

I changed my DNS to my new server on iPage. My previous server was AWS and now I got this error message:

[image]

I used to access to my site from here http://matchmakinginstitute.ipage.com/ but now is not working either.

So both links:

http://matchmakinginstitute.ipage.com/
http://matchmakinginstitute.com/

Are showing me the same error. I checked my error log file and I have only 1 line:

> 1479164063:
>   /hermes/bosnaweb03a/b2364/ipg.matchmakinginstitute/ssv3_payload_extractor-aU0H89Pshc.php
>   startup

Does somebody know what else can I do to fix this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Check your error logs for more details.

Comment: DNS is server related, not code related. Question's off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind DNS changes can take up to 48 hours to take effect.
If it's still not working after 48 hours i would suggest reverting the DNS changes and try again.

https://godaddy.com/help/what-factors-affect-dns-propagation-time-1746

Your page seems to be working fine now, did waiting do the trick ?

Comment: But until the DNS changes take effect, the website should keep running on the old server, isn't it ?

Comment: Not always, i did DNS changes myself a few days ago and the page went down instant but the changes to the new server took 18 hours.